# JavaScript auto currency converter based on geolocation

Tags: html, css

I have a custom pricing table which I built using  html and css but I have a problem with this pricing table. I am trying to serve my visitors the cost of a subscription plan based on their location using JavaScript but I am unable to do so. Please can someone help me with actual code to make my work easier.

Please this code is to be used on WordPress theme using wp coder plugin.

THIS IS THE HTML CODE

> ```
> <h1 class="suretips pricing plan">
>   <br>
> </h1>
> <div class="pricing-table">
>   <div class="ptable-item">
>     <div class="ptable-single">
>       <div class="ptable-header">
>         <div class="ptable-title">
>           <h2>Daily</h2>
>         </div>
>         <div class="ptable-price">
>           <h2><small> 
> ₦</small>150<span>/ D</span></h2>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="ptable-body">
>         <div class="ptable-description">
>           <ul>
>             <li>Very High Accuracy</li>
>             <li>Daily Email Notifications</li>
>             <li>24/7 Customer Support</li>
>             <li>Daily Sport News</li>
>           </ul>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="ptable-footer">
>         <div class="ptable-action">
>           <a href="https://suretips.com.ng/1-5-odds-daily/">Select Plan</a>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="ptable-item featured-item">
>     <div class="ptable-single">
>       <div class="ptable-header">
>         <div class="ptable-status">
>           <span>Hot</span>
>         </div>
>         <div class="ptable-title">
>           <h2>Weekly</h2>
>         </div>
>         <div class="ptable-price">
>           <h2><small> 
> ₦</small>800<span>/ W</span></h2>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="ptable-body">
>         <div class="ptable-description">
>           <ul>
>             <li>Very High Accuracy</li>
>             <li>Daily Email Notification</li>
>             <li>24/7 Customer Support</li>
>             <li>Daily Sport News</li>
>           </ul>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="ptable-footer">
>         <div class="ptable-action">
>           <a href="https://suretips.com.ng/1-5-odds-weekly/">Select Plan</a>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="ptable-item">
>     <div class="ptable-single">
>       <div class="ptable-header">
>         <div class="ptable-title">
>           <h2>Monthly</h2>
>         </div>
>         <div class="ptable-price">
>           <h2><small> 
> ₦</small>2500<span>/ </span></h2>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="ptable-body">
>         <div class="ptable-description">
>           <ul>
>             <li>Very High Accuracy</li>
>             <li>Daily Email Notification</li>
>             <li>24/7 Customer Support</li>
>             <li>Daily Sport News</li>
>           </ul>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>       <div class="ptable-footer">
>         <div class="ptable-action">
>           <a href="https://suretips.com.ng/1-5-odds-monthly/">Select Plan</a>
>         </div>
>       </div>
>     </div>
>   </div>
> </div>
> ```

THIS IS THE CSS CODE

> ```
> *,
> *::before,
> *::after {
>   box-sizing: border-box;
> }
>
> body {
>   margin: 0;
>   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
>   background: #ffffff;
> }
>
> h1.demo-title {
>   text-align: center;
>   font-size: 30px;
>   font-weight: 600;
>   color: #2A293E;
>   letter-spacing: 2px;
> }
>
> h1.demo-title a {
>   font-size: 16px;
>   font-weight: 300;
> }
>
> .pricing-table {
>   display: flex;
>   flex-flow: row wrap;
>   width: 100%;
>   max-width: 1100px;
>   margin: 0 auto;
>   background: #ffffff;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-item {
>   width: 33.33%;
>   padding: 0 15px;
>   margin-bottom: 30px;
> }
>
> @media (max-width: 992px) {
>   .pricing-table .ptable-item {
>     width: 33.33%;
>   }
> }
>
> @media (max-width: 768px) {
>   .pricing-table .ptable-item {
>     width: 50%;
>   }
> }
>
> @media (max-width: 576px) {
>   .pricing-table .ptable-item {
>     width: 100%;
>   }
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-single {
>   position: relative;
>   width: 100%;
>   overflow: hidden;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-header,
> .pricing-table .ptable-body,
> .pricing-table .ptable-footer {
>   position: relative;
>   width: 100%;
>   text-align: center;
>   overflow: hidden;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-status ,
> .pricing-table .ptable-title,
> .pricing-table .ptable-price,
> .pricing-table .ptable-description,
> .pricing-table .ptable-action {
>   position: relative;
>   width: 100%;
>   text-align: center;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-single {
>   background: #f6f8fa;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-single:hover {
>   box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999999;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-header {
>   margin: 0 30px;
>   padding: 30px 0 45px 0;
>   width: auto;
>   background: #2A293E;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-header::before,
> .pricing-table .ptable-header::after {
>   content: "";
>   position: absolute;
>   bottom: 0;
>   width: 0;
>   height: 0;
>   border-bottom: 100px solid #f6f8fa;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-header::before {
>   right: 50%;
>   border-right: 250px solid transparent;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-header::after {
>   left: 50%;
>   border-left: 250px solid transparent;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-item.featured-item .ptable-header {
>   background: #FF6F61;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-status {
>   margin-top: -30px;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-status span {
>   position: relative;
>   display: inline-block;
>   width: 50px;
>   height: 30px;
>   padding: 5px 0;
>   text-align: center;
>   color: #FF6F61;
>   font-size: 14px;
>   font-weight: 300;
>   letter-spacing: 1px;
>   background: #2A293E;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-status span::before,
> .pricing-table .ptable-status span::after {
>   content: "";
>   position: absolute;
>   bottom: 0;
>   width: 0;
>   height: 0;
>   border-bottom: 10px solid #FF6F61;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-status span::before {
>   right: 50%;
>   border-right: 25px solid transparent;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-status span::after {
>   left: 50%;
>   border-left: 25px solid transparent;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-title h2 {
>   color: #ffffff;
>   font-size: 24px;
>   font-weight: 300;
>   letter-spacing: 2px;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-price h2 {
>   margin: 0;
>   color: #ffffff;
>   font-size: 45px;
>   font-weight: 700;
>   margin-left: 15px;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-price h2 small {
>   position: absolute;
>   font-size: 18px;
>   font-weight: 300;
>   margin-top: 16px;
>   margin-left: -15px;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-price h2 span {
>   margin-left: 3px;
>   font-size: 16px;
>   font-weight: 300;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-body {
>   padding: 20px 0;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-description ul {
>   margin: 0;
>   padding: 0;
>   list-style: none;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-description ul li {
>   color: #2A293E;
>   font-size: 14px;
>   font-weight: 300;
>   letter-spacing: 1px;
>   padding: 7px;
>   border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-description ul li:last-child {
>   border: none;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-footer {
>   padding-bottom: 30px;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-action a {
>   display: inline-block;
>   padding: 10px 20px;
>   color: #FF6F61;
>   font-size: 14px;
>   font-weight: 500;
>   letter-spacing: 2px;
>   text-decoration: none;
>   background: #2A293E;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-action a:hover {
>   color: #2A293E;
>   background: #FF6F61;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-item.featured-item .ptable-action a {
>   color: #2A293E;
>   background: #FF6F61;
> }
>
> .pricing-table .ptable-item.featured-item .ptable-action a:hover {
>   color: #FF6F61;
>   background: #2A293E;
> }
> ```

I will be grateful if someone could help.

Comment: Neither the HTML or CSS code helps understanding the problem. Maybe JavaScript can help, but you haven't tried to write some, and maybe this can be solved in your WordPress code, but then you would need to ask is as a new/other question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to get the current country of your clients:

```js
function callback(response) {
  console.log(response);
  alert(response.country_name);
}

$.ajax({
  url: "https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/",
  dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #ffffff;
}

h1.demo-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #2A293E;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

h1.demo-title a {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.pricing-table {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-item {
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 0 15px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .pricing-table .ptable-item {
    width: 33.33%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .pricing-table .ptable-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .pricing-table .ptable-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.pricing-table .ptable-single {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-header,
.pricing-table .ptable-body,
.pricing-table .ptable-footer {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-status,
.pricing-table .ptable-title,
.pricing-table .ptable-price,
.pricing-table .ptable-description,
.pricing-table .ptable-action {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-single {
  background: #f6f8fa;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-single:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999999;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-header {
  margin: 0 30px;
  padding: 30px 0 45px 0;
  width: auto;
  background: #2A293E;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-header::before,
.pricing-table .ptable-header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 100px solid #f6f8fa;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-header::before {
  right: 50%;
  border-right: 250px solid transparent;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-header::after {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 250px solid transparent;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-item.featured-item .ptable-header {
  background: #FF6F61;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-status {
  margin-top: -30px;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-status span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF6F61;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  background: #2A293E;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-status span::before,
.pricing-table .ptable-status span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #FF6F61;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-status span::before {
  right: 50%;
  border-right: 25px solid transparent;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-status span::after {
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 25px solid transparent;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-title h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-price h2 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-price h2 small {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-price h2 span {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-body {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-description ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-description ul li {
  color: #2A293E;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 7px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-description ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-footer {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-action a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #FF6F61;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #2A293E;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-action a:hover {
  color: #2A293E;
  background: #FF6F61;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-item.featured-item .ptable-action a {
  color: #2A293E;
  background: #FF6F61;
}

.pricing-table .ptable-item.featured-item .ptable-action a:hover {
  color: #FF6F61;
  background: #2A293E;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="suretips pricing plan">
  <br>
</h1>
<div class="pricing-table">
  <div class="ptable-item">
    <div class="ptable-single">
      <div class="ptable-header">
        <div class="ptable-title">
          <h2>Daily</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="ptable-price">
          <h2><small> 
₦</small>150<span>/ D</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ptable-body">
        <div class="ptable-description">
          <ul>
            <li>Very High Accuracy</li>
            <li>Daily Email Notifications</li>
            <li>24/7 Customer Support</li>
            <li>Daily Sport News</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ptable-footer">
        <div class="ptable-action">
          <a href="https://suretips.com.ng/1-5-odds-daily/">Select Plan</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ptable-item featured-item">
    <div class="ptable-single">
      <div class="ptable-header">
        <div class="ptable-status">
          <span>Hot</span>
        </div>
        <div class="ptable-title">
          <h2>Weekly</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="ptable-price">
          <h2><small> 
₦</small>800<span>/ W</span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ptable-body">
        <div class="ptable-description">
          <ul>
            <li>Very High Accuracy</li>
            <li>Daily Email Notification</li>
            <li>24/7 Customer Support</li>
            <li>Daily Sport News</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ptable-footer">
        <div class="ptable-action">
          <a href="https://suretips.com.ng/1-5-odds-weekly/">Select Plan</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="ptable-item">
    <div class="ptable-single">
      <div class="ptable-header">
        <div class="ptable-title">
          <h2>Monthly</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="ptable-price">
          <h2><small> 
₦</small>2500<span>/ </span></h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ptable-body">
        <div class="ptable-description">
          <ul>
            <li>Very High Accuracy</li>
            <li>Daily Email Notification</li>
            <li>24/7 Customer Support</li>
            <li>Daily Sport News</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ptable-footer">
        <div class="ptable-action">
          <a href="https://suretips.com.ng/1-5-odds-monthly/">Select Plan</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This code didn't work. I inserted it in my wp coder plugin on my WordPress but it didn't work.